# use managed identity to access azure keyvault in kubernetes cluster which is hosted on azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-managed-identity

I know with Azure Kubernetes service we can use managed identities to access azure resources like keyvaults. But i'm trying to learn if same procedure can be applied to a kubernetes cluster which is hosted on azure. My aim is to have kubernetes cluster in azure with 2 worker and 2 controller nodes but pods residing on those nodes should access azure keyvault with managed identity method similar to AKS. Is there anyway we can do it without coding in application?

I understand the scope of this question is big but it is really helpful if somebody provide any high level steps ?

thanks,
Santosh

Comment: Assigning a managed identity directly to a pod is an add-on, here: https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity#getting-started

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, i tried above solution but mic pods are not starting because "Could not get the MIC client: read /etc/kubernetes/azure.json: is a directory" error. Indeed on worker node that is a directory.  since i created a cluster without aks and aks engine is that file something manually created and keep it there?

Answer (score 0):

That's totally possible. [AAD Pod identities](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity) rely on AAD (Azure Active Directory) and its permissions.

At the end AKS will have an infrastructure behind the scenes. So if you plan to not use AKS but install a cluster by yourself, for example with AKS engine, you can use AAD Pod Identities  / Managed Instances.

All you need is that those machines reside in "Azure" and rely on what is called [Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service). Even you can enroll new machine instances coming outside from Azure with the project [ARC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-arc/). Anyway I cannot talk about it with Managed instances since I have not used it, anyway it should follow a similar pattern.

Here you have a good article that explains AAD Pod identities:

https://itnext.io/the-right-way-of-accessing-azure-services-from-inside-your-azure-kubernetes-cluster-14a335767680

Comment: Hi, this is more concentrated on AKS. But i have cluster installed separately on azure.

Comment: So you don't want to use AD? AAD Pod identities relies on AD and Kubernetes (not AKS per se) which I think is what you ask...If you don't want to rely on AD integration that is another use case.

Comment: Hi, I want to use AD only. But here setup fails at "Deploy aad-pod-identity to your cluster" step only. MIC pods are crashed with "Could not get the MIC client: read /etc/kubernetes/azure.json: is a directory" error.